# restorablePush then pushAndRemoveUntil results in error (flutter)

Tags: flutter

What I want to achieve:

- Screen 1 is the initial screen, and goes to Screen 2 (via `restorablePush`)
- Screen 2 is a restorable page, and goes to Screen 3 (via `restorablePush`)
- Screen 3 is a restorable page, and goes back to Screen 1 (via `pushAndRemoveUntil`)

The restoring stuff works fine, but when I go back to Screen 1 from Screen 3 then kill the app and reopen it, I get this failed assertion error:

_history.isNotEmpty:
All routes returned by onGenerateInitialRoutes are not restorable.
Please make sure that all routes returned by onGenerateInitialRoutes
have their RouteSettings defined with names that are defined in the
app's routes table.

I've look at `onGeneralInitialRoutes` but I can't figure out how to solve this. I also tried doing everything with named routes, but it didn't change anything.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Screen1(),
      restorationScopeId: 'root',
    );
  }
}

class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen1> createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  static Route<void> _myRouteBuilder(BuildContext context, Object? arguments) {
    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => const Screen2(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.restorablePush(context, _myRouteBuilder);
            },
            child: const Text('Go to Screen 2')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen2> createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  static Route<void> _myRouteBuilder(BuildContext context, Object? arguments) {
    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => const Screen3(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Screen 2')),
        body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.restorablePush(context, _myRouteBuilder),
          child: const Text('Go to Screen 3'),
        )));
  }
}

class Screen3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Screen 3')),
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen1()),
                ((route) => false)),
            child: const Text('Go back to Screen 1'),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It may be via `RouteSettings(name:"/myRoute")`, because this property is used to identify the screens within the route map. But I'm not sure, I need to study restorablePush.

Comment: @Chance I did try that too but it did not work:(

Comment: This is now an open issue on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112457